# How to check if a particular course exists in an array of registered courses using Nodejs mongodb and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a course registration portal. Everything is working but i want a way stopping: a student from registering the same course over and over again here are my code:

```
FIRST I CREATE A STUDENT SCHEMA
var studentSchema = new Schema({
    firstname:{type: String, required: true},
    middlename:{type: String, required: true},
    lastname:{type: String, required: true},
    department:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'department', required: true },
    Courses:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'course'}],
  });
```

The student schema has  a sub-document Courses which is an array of courseSchema

```
var courseSchema = new Schema({
   title: {type: String, required: true},
   code:{type: String, required: true, unique: true},
   unit:{type: String, required: true},
   level:{type: String, required: true},
   department:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'department'}
});
```

I also create an API to get all the courses in mongodb where student.department is equal to course.department here is the code

```
router.get('/student/getcourses/:studentid', function(req, res){
if (!req.params.studentid) {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
        "message": "Not found, studentid is required"
    });
        return;
}
Student
.findOne({_id : req.params.studentid})
.exec(function(err, student){
    if (err) {
        sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
    }else{
        Course
        .find({department : student.department})
        .populate('department')
        .exec(function(err, courses){
            if (err) {
                sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
            }else{
                sendJSONresponse(res, 200, courses);
            }
        });
    }
 });
});
```

I also create an API that will register a particular course for a student here is the code

```
router.post('/student/courseReg/:studentid', function(req, res){
if (!req.params.studentid) {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
        "message": "Not found, studentid is required"
    });
        return;
}
Student
.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.studentid, {$push: {regCourses:req.body.course}})
.exec(function(err, student){
    if (err) {
        sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
    }else{
        sendJSONresponse(res, 200, " registration successfull");
    }
 });
});
```

on the front-end with angularjs here is what i did

```
$http.get('/api/student/getcourses/' + $scope.studentid)
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.courses = data ; 
})
.error(function (e) {
    return e;
});
$scope.register = function(course){
            $http.post('/api/student/courseReg/' + $scope.studentid, {course: course})
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
};
```

and here is the html code

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table"> 
         <thead> 
             <tr> 
                 <th>Title</th> 
                 <th>Code</th> 
                 <th>Department</th> 
                 <th>level</th>                      
             </tr> 
         </thead> 
             <tbody> 
                 <tr ng-repeat="course in courses |  filter: adminfilter"> 
                     <td>{{course.name}}</td> 
                     <td>{{course.code}}</td> 
                     <td>{{course.department.name}}</td> 
                     <td>{{course.level}}</td> 
                     <td>
                        <button  ng-click="register(course._id)"  class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Register</button>
                     </td>                      
                   </tr> 
             </tbody>
         </table>
      </div
```

and here is the output
[Outout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9OJQ.jpg)

everything works but i want a way of hiding the register button of the corresponding course when it exists in the student.regCourses array. can any body help me?
[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz3Ya.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
function CallSomeFunction(courseName, courseArray) // add this function in angular file
{
   if(/*courseArray contains courseName*/){
        return true;
   }

   return false;
}

ng-show = CallSomeFunction(courseName, courseArray); // add this line in button tag
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add info for each course if the student is already registered to it:

```js
Course
        .find({department : student.department})
        .populate('department')
        .exec(function(err, courses){
            if (err) {
                sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
            }else{
              courses.forEach(course => {
                course.isRegistered = student.Courses.indexOf(course._id) > -1;
                }
                sendJSONresponse(res, 200, courses);
            }
        });
```

In html:

```js
<button  
  ng-if="!course.isRegistered"
  ng-click="register(course._id)"
  class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Register</button>
```

Pay attention that:
1. Maybe setting course.isRegistered won't work since it is not in schema. Try using the set method of mongoose.
2. Hiding the resgister button isn't enough since the user can send a request with any course id he wants. In server when you register the student to a course, make sure he is not registered already by adding a condition to the query:

```js
update({_id: req.params.studentid,
       Courses: {$nin: [req.body.course]}}, {$push: {regCourses:req.body.course}})
```

Comment: am sorry i don't really understand  your code, can you give me a clear code of what you meant with respect to what i have posted. so i can see where i have gone wrong in my code

Comment: What exactly you don't understand? The first is when the user asks for a list of courses. The second is the button your table. The third is where you used findByIdAndUpdate